# How to print a each item in list without weird spacing?

Tags: python, list, printing, console

I have a list gathered from a text file, `f`, named `fList`. I want to print each item in list separately on a new line and I used the following.

```py
f.seek(0)
fList = f.readlines()
items = fList[::2] #Every other value
    
print("\n Catalogue Items: \n")
print(*items)
```

When printing in the console, the first item always has a weird spacing. Image of output in console [image: here.]
The first item always does not follow the spacing of the rest when printed.

Comment: please provide a sample of the file that includes the first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text appears to include carriage return characters.

Printing `*items` only adds the spaces ***between*** elements, not the carriage returns, or a space before the first item.

Assuming you want those carriage returns, just add a space to the print statement (to add a space before the first element too), or use `join` to avoid adding the spaces between elements.

```
print(''.join(items)) # no spaces
```

Or...

```
print('', *items) # consistent single spaces
```

Or...

```
print(' ', '  '.join(items)) # consist double spaces
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the var.strip() function, it gets rid of spaces on both sides

Comment: can you show how exactly they'd use that?